# 1l for long, 1f for float, 1d for double, what about byte?

Tags: java, casting, initialization, byte

1l for long, 1f for float, 1d for double, what about byte?

```java
long l = 1l;
float f = 1f;
double d = 1d;
// byte b = 1?;
```

What's the equivalent for `byte`? Does it exist?

Comment: Is http://www.herongyang.com/Java/Byte-Data-Type-Implicit-Casting.html of any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no suffix you can append to a numeric literal to make it a `byte`.

See [3.10 Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10) in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast to byte like this:

```
byte b = 1;

b = (byte) 5;
```

Since by default these numeric constant are treated as int in Java.

Comment: Except that it is not necessary in this case, because the literal is a compile-time constant. `byte b = 1;` is perfectly legal.

Comment: yes, `byte b=1` works fine, unfortunately for every other operation but the initialization the cast is again necessary. Even the seemingly harmless `b+=1`. I understand that this must be like this, it's just... annoying to cast everytime

Answer (score 1):

there is no suffix you can append a numeric literal

Answer (score 1):

There is no such suffix for bytes, see the [Java Language Specification section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

```
DecimalIntegerLiteral:
    DecimalNumeral IntegerTypeSuffix(opt)

IntegerTypeSuffix: one of
    l L
```

Note `(opt)` signifies it is optional. So to assign you need to explicitly cast using `(byte) 1`.