# Java: what is 1d?

Tags: java, double

Came across the following expression on Java and I have no idea what "1d" means (`r` is an integer). There are also [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701795/1l-for-long-1f-for-float-1d-for-double-what-about-byte) for longs, doubles... What are they and what are they used for?

```
double y = r / (Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1d);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a `double` literal.

Comment: ... and for avoiding integer division.

Comment: Equivalent to casting then?

Comment: Kind of shorthand for 1.0, and it implies double-precision. `1f` would do the same thing only it would be single-precision.

Comment: No. It will not get casted, it originally creates a double value, just like `1.0`.

Comment: Not casting. This is a literal value. By default Java interpret a number like 1 as an int. If you intend a floating point value like 1.0 instead then you add the suffix d t indicate that the literal value is to be interpreted as a double.

Comment: Why do this vs. multiplying one of the integers (like `r` above) by 1.0?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sufix `d` after number means `double`, sufix `f` means `float`.

You can express double literal in eight ways: `1.0`, `1d`, `1D`, `1.0d`, `1.0D`, `1.`, `1.d`, `1.D` and not truly double literal: `(double)1`. In the last example `1` is the literal, it is an `int` but then I cast it to `double`.

In your expression: `double y = r / (Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1d);` parentheses increase priority of expression so the `(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1d)` will be evaluated first and because this is `intValue + doubleValue` the outcome will be of type `double` so `r / (Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1d)` will be also a `double`.